# Ubuntu 18.04.1, cannot add PPA wireguard/ubuntu/wireguard

Tags: ubuntu, wireguard

I'm trying to install WireGurad on my fresh vanilla Ubuntu 18.04.1 machine, by following the instructions from [WireGuard website](https://www.wireguard.com/install/). But when I try to execute very first command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireguard/wireguard
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~wireguard/ubuntu/wireguard'.
ERROR: '~wireguard' user or team does not exist.
```

Although there is WireGuard page at launchpad.net: https://launchpad.net/~wireguard/+archive/ubuntu/wireguard.

Any suggestion on how to install it?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: The problem was in proxy settings (as [the link from the accepted answer suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971877/cannot-add-ppa-user-or-team-does-not-exist/1036627)). After exporting HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables, everything works.

Comment: Are you connected to the Internet?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1781917

in fact it can be anything related to networking malfunction

Comment: Note that you should not need to use the Wireguard PPA with Ubuntu 18.04.1 -- it is deprecated and is supposed to only be useful for Ubuntu 14.04, as per the warning when trying to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could manually add the following to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireguard/wireguard/ubuntu bionic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireguard/wireguard/ubuntu bionic main
```

And then `sudo apt-get update`.

You could see these steps in the WireGuard Launchpad page - reveal by expanding "Technical details about this PPA" and picking "Bionic 18.04" in the drop down.

The following post suggests that this error from `add-apt-repository` may be due to apt proxy settings, and gives a possible fix: [Cannot add PPA - “user or team does not exist”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971877/cannot-add-ppa-user-or-team-does-not-exist/1036627).

Comment: Continue scrolling for up to date answer.

Answer (score 8):

**Info from [https://launchpad.net/~wireguard](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewireguard)** : This formerly was responsible for producing a PPA for WireGuard on Ubuntu. That functionality has now been folded into Ubuntu itself, so our old PPA has been removed. Simply run `apt install wireguard` on all Ubuntus ≥ 16.04.

Answer (score -1):

PPA for WireGuard has now been folded into Ubuntu itself; as per:
[https://launchpad.net/~wireguard](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewireguard)